# python re.search can't find existing pattern

Tags: python

```
import re

pattern = 'E8 AC 82 18 00 48 89 5C 24 08 48 8B B3'
pattern2 = '5C 24 08 48 8B B3'

code = bytes.fromhex('0D 00 00 84 C0 74 0A 8A 44 24 0E 88 05 0F EB 4A 00 48 83 C4 38 5B 41 5E C3 CC 55 41 57 41 56 41 55 41 54 53 48 81 EC 68 02 00 00 48 89 FB 48 8B BF 28 04 00 00 E8 92 09 39 00 48 8B B3 D8 02 00 00 BF 09 DB 55 00 BA 88 13 00 00 E8 AC 82 18 00 48 89 5C 24 08 48 8B B3 D8 02 00 00 BF 4E DD 55 00 BA 98 3A 00 00 E8 91 82 18 00 BF A8 50 A1 00 E8 EB 13 4A 00 83 25 EC 83 4B 00 00 31 ED 4C 8B 35 6B 83 4B 00 41 BC 60 50 A1 00 C7 44 24 10 00 00 00 00 4D 39 E6 74 44 4C 89 F3 49 8B 46 40 44 8B 68 1C 44 01 ED 44 8B 78 18 4C 89 F7 E8 4E 7C F5 FF 49 89 C6 45 09 EF 75 D9 BE 60 50 A1 00 48')

offset = re.search(bytes.fromhex(pattern), code)

print(offset)
```

Return none

```
offset = re.search(bytes.fromhex(pattern2), code)

print(offset2)
```

Return <re.Match object; span=(83, 88), match=b'$\x08H\x8b\xb3'>

What's wrong with longer pattern?

Comment: There may be some characters special to regular expressions in the bytes (like `()[]+*`). Better use bytes' "find" or "index" method instead.

Comment: Solved... So easy... 

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('5C 24')
b'\\$'
```

In the pattern, the backslash gets interpreted away to escape the `$`. But in `code` it stays and prevents the pattern from matching (because the pattern doesn't match a backslash).

The second pattern doesn't have that issue, as it only starts matching *after* the backslash.

Comment: Thank You for the explanation, but is there a way to match it with whole pattern (I need regexp pattern)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you want that pattern to match, you need to adapt the `code` value.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

pattern = bytes.fromhex('E8 AC 82 18 00 48 89 5C 24 08 48 8B B3'

code = bytes.fromhex('0D 00 00 84 C0 74 0A 8A 44 24 0E 88 05 0F EB 4A 00 48 83 C4 38 5B 41 5E C3 CC 55 41 57 41 56 41 55 41 54 53 48 81 EC 68 02 00 00 48 89 FB 48 8B BF 28 04 00 00 E8 92 09 39 00 48 8B B3 D8 02 00 00 BF 09 DB 55 00 BA 88 13 00 00 E8 AC 82 18 00 48 89 5C 24 08 48 8B B3 D8 02 00 00 BF 4E DD 55 00 BA 98 3A 00 00 E8 91 82 18 00 BF A8 50 A1 00 E8 EB 13 4A 00 83 25 EC 83 4B 00 00 31 ED 4C 8B 35 6B 83 4B 00 41 BC 60 50 A1 00 C7 44 24 10 00 00 00 00 4D 39 E6 74 44 4C 89 F3 49 8B 46 40 44 8B 68 1C 44 01 ED 44 8B 78 18 4C 89 F7 E8 4E 7C F5 FF 49 89 C6 45 09 EF 75 D9 BE 60 50 A1 00 48')

offset = re.search(re.escape(pattern), code)

print(offset)
```

Solved.. So easy, but first I need use brain and read manual...